# serve static file for all requests to a directory and it's subdirectories

Tags: nginx

I want to show a specific static page for all requests to a directory and it's subdirectories.

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/folder/* -> /www/external/static.html
```

I have tried the following which sort of works, but it doesn't show the file, it downloads the file;

```
location ~ ^/folder/* {
    alias      /www/external/index.html;   
}
```

I just want it to display the content of index.html for any requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `try_files` instead of `alias` to specify the file to retrieve. This should also set the correct Content-Type so that the file is displayed rather than downloaded.

For example:

```
location ^~ /folder/ { 
    root /www/external;
    try_files /index.html =404;
}
```

The `=404` is not reached if `/www/external/index.html` exists, but is necessary as [try_files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) requires at least two parameters.

---

I have used a [prefix location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) with the `^~` operator, which matches any URL that **begins with** `/folder/`.

You used the regular expression `^/folder/*` which matches `/folder`, `/folder/`, `/folder//`, `/folder///`, etc.

I am not sure what your requirement is. If you only want to match URLs that are directories and subdirectories, **but not the files within**, use a regular expression that matches URLs that begin with `/folder` and **end with** a `/`.

For example:

```
location ~* ^/folder/(.*/)?$
```